# What does the abbreviation 'z. Bw.' mean?

Tags: abbreviation, mathematics

What does the abbreviation 'z. Bw.' mean?

To be precise, the context is Mathematics.

Comment: Do have a little more context?

Comment: »the context is Mathematics« doesn't help really much. It would help much more, if you could post a piece of Text (at least one complete sentence, better a paragraph) that contains this abbreviation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a context of mathematics "*z. Bw.*" is probably

> **z**um **B**e**w**eis

which is "as proof".

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes used instead of the Latin QED, although I'm not sure they cover exactly the same meaning.

Comment: @Mast da kenne ich nur wzbw (was zu beweisen war), aber heute macht man doch eher ein Kästchen ;)